PDFlib embed font
I am able to embed fonts before, using the code below.
pdf_set_parameter($pdf, "FontOutline", "Times=$fontdir/times.ttf");
$font = pdf_findfont($pdf, "Times", "winansi", 1);
pdf_setfont($pdf,$font,$font_size);
$p->setfont( $font,$fontsize);

But it seems this is now deprecated in new PDFLib version. I am now trying the code below as shown in the cookbook.
$p->set_option("FontOutline=Times=".$fontdir."/times.ttf");
$times_font = $p->load_font("Times", "unicode","");
$p->setfont( $times_font,$fontsize);

I am getting this error message: PDFlibException: Option 'FontOutline' has odd number of values...
Please help.

From the docs it sounds like you use either set_options or load_font
https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/fonts/font_configuration/
"If you know the font name and the font file name ... you can simply load the font", "Alternatively, you can supply an absolute path name such as p.set_option ..."


I am getting this error message: PDFlibException: Option 'FontOutline' has odd number of values...

indeed, the option you apply is wrong.
You might find this well explained in the PDFlib 10.0.2 Tutorial, chapter 6.3.4:

For a detailed introduction into the powerful PDFlib option list, please check out PDFlib 10.0.2 API reference, 1.1 "Option Lists".
So I expect when you use
$p->set_option("FontOutline={Times=".$fontdir."/times.ttf"});
$times_font = $p->load_font("Times", "unicode","");
$p->setfont( $times_font,$fontsize);

Or you specify $fontdir as SearchPath and then simple use:
$p->set_option("SearchPath={{".$fontdir."} {/further/directory}");
$p->set_option("FontOutline={Times=times.ttf"});
$times_font = $p->load_font("Times", "unicode","");
$p->setfont( $times_font,$fontsize);

Please honor also, that you can specify the font (fontname or fonthandle and fontsize) also in the option list for fit_textline() of add/create_textflow().
This make it often much more easier, as always set the font with setfont()
About font embedding:
You can control the font embedding with the load_font() option embedding. Since PDFlib 10 this the default is true. When you use an outdated PDFlib version, you have to set embedding=true as well when loading the font.

Turns out I was missing braces after "FontOutline=". Once I added that it worked out perfectly. Thank you.
